# CSS+Vueitfy Fill remaining height and add scrollbar if needed

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue and Vuetify to create a mobile site that looks similar to the Youtube native app when a user is watching a live video. I would like the chat component to fill the available height underneath the video while in portrait mode. Currently using `d-flex flex-column` on the div containing the chats but the div still runs off screen (the whole app scrolls). I would like to avoid calculating the height manually on resize, what should I do?

EDIT: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/davidjohnbell/pen/bGGWLEb)

```html
<v-app>
  <v-app-bar app fixed>
    <!-- brevity -->
  </v-app-bar>
  <v-content style="padding: 56px;">
    <player/>
    <details-bar/>
    <chats class="d-flex flex-column"/> <!-- a div that should be contained between show bar and bottom of screen -->
  </v-content>
</v-app>
```

[image: picture of current app]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the flex on the `v-content` and setting `flex-grow` on the `chats` component? For example:

```
<v-content style="padding: 56px;" class="d-flex flex-column">
    <player/>
    <details-bar/>
    <chats style="flex-grow: 1;"/> <!-- a div that should be contained between show bar and bottom of screen -->
  </v-content>
```

Theoretically, this should give `player` and `details-bar` a constant height and give the rest of the space to `chats`. If you can just limit the height of `v-content` to the height of the window, you should be good. Hopefully, Vuetify does that automatically, but if not, you could try manually setting `max-height` maybe?

Comment: I tried your solution without much success but I could be doing something wrong. I've edited my question with a codepen which you can also find here https://codepen.io/davidjohnbell/pen/bGGWLEb